# Trying to use Room on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to create an app using Room persistence library in Android Studio. The problem is that is not working when I try to run, it gives me this message:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   > java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open_utf8([BI)V

I am following everything from this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAHAQunQkDE tutorial, and it worked with the guy on the video. Maybe is something that I should install, but I dont know what. (I double checked every step on the video and everything is ok, except that mine dont run)

Comment: Try clean build.

Comment: I have also seen this, but only on our jenkins builds (running linux). Using Android Studio on Windows I have not seen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error in this case was due to `/tmp` being mounted with the `noexec` flag. If you're on linux, you can check if this is the case with a `grep /tmp /proc/mounts` to see the mount options. The sqlite JDBC repo has [an issue](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/97) about this problem.

In my case, I fixed it by remounting `/tmp` without the `noexec` option. If you don't want to (or can't), it seems to be suggested to set `GRADLE_OPTS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/some/other/path. The issue linked above also mentions setting`org.sqlite.tmpdir`. Unfortunately, neither of those seemed to work for my by setting gradle opts in Android Studio.